# Github pulling does not work in - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I'm trying to pull last commit that I made on github, and though I get no errors, I see no changes in the code. I messed up my schema file, but after I pull the code it does not change at all.

I searched here on stack and the solution that worked for others didn't work for me, and this is also my first time that I'm  pulling code from github, so I could've probably done something wrong.

I used this code:

```
git fetch origin controller-generator
git git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

This is what I get as the output

```
HEAD is now at 1fb8c97 Integrated friendly routes gem
```

'Integrated friendly routes gem' is my last commit that I want to pull, but nothing changes. I don't know if I need one more step or whatever it goes with it.

This is what I have in commit db file

[image]

And when I pull this, I get this

[image]

The last one should not be there.
This is output

```
equalsign:~/workspace/BlogAndPort/db/migrate (controller-generator) $ git reset --hard 1fb8c97d64f389904b3048fb2850fcfd8425cd36
HEAD is now at 1fb8c97 Integrated friendly routes gem
equalsign:~/workspace/BlogAndPort/db/migrate (controller-generator) $ git push -f origin HEAD 
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Everything up-to-date
```

The problem is still the same as shown in the pictures. db files did not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, you are asking to `reset` your `local/master` with `origin/master`.

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

You can back (`hard reset`) to a commit that was working for you.

```
$ git reflog                     # copy the commit-sha where you want to back/reset

$ git reset --hard <commit-sha>  # reset to the commit
```

Now, if all things are ok. Then Force (`-f`) Push to remote.

```
$ git push -f origin HEAD        # update remote branch
```

Comment: It's strange. When I use origin/master it gets me my Initial commit on master branch properly, but when I use this origin/controller-generator it does not. It still has that file in schema

Comment: Eventhough the output is the same

Comment: So, what exactly you want now? Can you attach a demo example in your OP (Original Post)? You can also  back (`reset`) to a commit that was working for you.

Comment: Yes I want that. To reset completely to a commit that was working for me. How do I do that ?

Comment: It's apparently something wrong with that particular commit, because all the other works.